# Container multi stage build with pyrender for distroless

Tags: python, docker, debian, distroless, pyrender

I have the following multi stage build to add pyrender into a distroless continer

```
FROM debian:11-slim as build
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --yes python3-venv gcc libpython3-dev \
    wget git ca-certificates python python3-pip libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev && \
    python3 -m venv /venv && \
    /venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

RUN /venv/bin/pip install pyrender pyopengl PyOpenGL_accelerate

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11

COPY --from=build /usr/lib /usr/lib
COPY --from=build /usr/include /usr/include
COPY --from=build /venv /venv
```

If I run pyrender inside `debian:11-slim` it works all well but when I move the libraries to distroless and try to run `import pyrender` I get

```
File "/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/glx.py", line 20, in GL
    raise ImportError("Unable to load OpenGL library", *err.args)
ImportError: ('Unable to load OpenGL library', 'GL: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory', 'GL', None)
```

or

```
File "/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrender/platforms/egl.py", line 83, in get_device_by_index
    raise ValueError('Invalid device ID ({})'.format(device_id, len(devices)))
ValueError: Invalid device ID (0)
```

I did set the env variable to `os.environ['PYOPENGL_PLATFORM'] = 'egl'`

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong? I would like to run it with distroless and not the debian image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these fixed my issues,

```
COPY --from=build /usr/bin /usr/bin
COPY --from=build /usr/lib /usr/lib
COPY --from=build /usr/share /usr/share
COPY --from=build /usr/local /usr/local
```

Although `/usr/bin` added a bunch of stuff that I don't need to be baked in the final image. however, I do not know which exact executable is needed in the bunch. If anyone knows please comment. For now this solves my issue without massively bloating the final image.